# How to return individual value from a json response in different URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am trying to learn how to retrieve a value from a json response in a different url.

Lets say the response is in this URL;
`https://my123domain.org/shop/index/.atgprofile.xhr.json`

The content in the response shows as follow;

`{"coolAuthorized":true,"cState":"anonymous","customerState":"anonymous","flowId":"23"}`

How can I simply return on my page the "flowId" value?

Thank for the help!

Comment: @Rayon  how is this an exact duplicate? I am trying to pull the value from a different url?

Comment: Every user will have different URL, concept is same and so is the question...